# NodeJS Remoção da pasta @types

Tags: node.js, permissões, file-permission

Eu tentei remover a pasta node_modules porque atualizei o nodejs e tive que reinstalar os módulos. No entanto, eu não tenho permissão para remover a pasta @types, nem mesmo com o administrador e eu queria saber como revomer essa pasta porque o npm não consegue instalar os módulos por falta de permissão a essa pasta. Fiz algo errado com o npm? Porque não consigo eliminar a pasta?
**EDIT:**
Windows 10
NodeJS  12.2.0
NPM     6.9.0

Comment: Qual o sistema operacional?

Comment: @GhértB.König editei a questão com informações adicionais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisando um pouco encontrei [este artigo](https://windowsreport.com/cant-delete-files-folders-icons-windows-10/).

Nele há varias formas de resolver este problema de permissão. Uma delas é remover através do prompt de comando (`cmd`). Abra o `cmd` e execute o comando:

```
del c:\caminho\para\arquivo\
```

Comment: Já tentei tanto o del como o rmdir, nenhum funcionou e em admin, não consigo mudar as permissões

Comment: consegui instalando um antivirus, desativando esse antivirus e depois fiz npm uninstall e eliminou a pasta